# What is stored in C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Performance\Monitor?

Tags: windows-8.1

I have a 120 GB SSD and the folder in question is taking a lot of space. Especially, there is a SecurityCache subfolder with hundreds of files taking gigabytes of space. Explorer reports it is taking 222 GB of space. It is obviously an error as my disk can store only 120GB. Probably it has to do with `perfmon.exe`, however, I'm wondering what data is it storing in that folder. Can I delete it? I tried googling about it, but found nothing useful.

Comment: You may be interested in my note on sparse files in [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/659427/194694).

Comment: Sounds like someone set up perfmon to log (data collector set) something.