# Where does metadata go when you save a file?

Tags: linux, unix, metadata

Say Johnny makes an EMPTY file. It is called `foobar.py`. When Johnny allows it to be executed, he runs `chmod 755 foobar.py`. The file now has the metadata of

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 johnny staff    0 Dec 27 22:53 foobar.py
```

Where is all that metadata stored in that file? The size of the file is 0, so how does it keep the metadata when it is transferred to another drive?

Comment: i'm no expert but i guess the general answer is that when you have a hard disk and you make 1+ partitions, then you format the partition with a file system, e.g. windows tends to use ntfs and linux might use ex2, then the bulk of that partition is for file contents, but some small amount of it is reserved for other stuff including metadata.

Comment: @barlop essentially correct. Both systems use some space for recording where files are stored; in NTFS the "master file table" stores the metadata, in ext2+ it's in "inodes".

Comment: @pjc50   thanks. and metadata aside, what is the name for the thing that is outside of the partitions? I suppose it depends whether the thing is MBR or GPT.. In MBR the thing is called the MBR.. What's it called in GPT? (I understand GPT has a legacy MBR but does it have its own thing too, outside of all the partitions?)

Comment: Related: (basically same thing, but question is specifically about Windows) [How are the file metadata stored in Windows?](http://superuser.com/q/659410/194694)

Comment: "chmod 755 ... The file now has the metadata of ... -rw-r--r-- ..." you mean -rwxr-xr-x.

Comment: It's stored *alongside* the file, but it's not counted as part of the file contents.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's not stored *in* that file. It's stored in the filesystem, and all parameters are copied manually one-by-one (though some cannot be copied at all).

That is, most operating systems don't really have a "copy file with metadata" call. The file-copy program just creates a new file named `foobar.py`, copies the whole 0 bytes of data, then uses [utime()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/utime.2.html) or [SetFileTime()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724933(v=vs.85).aspx) to make its modification time look the same as the original's. Likewise, file permissions would be "copied" by setting them anew using chmod() or by copying the POSIX ACL attribute.

Some metadata isn't copied. Setting ownership requires root privileges, so copies of someone else's files belong to you and occupy *your* disk quota. The ctime (attribute change time) is impossible to set manually on Unixes; btime (birth/creation time) is usually not copied either.

Compare `cp -a foo bar` (which copies metadata) and `cp foo bar` (which doesn't):

```
$ strace -v cp foo bar
…
open("foo", O_RDONLY)                   = 3
open("bar", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC)           = 4
read(3, "test\n", 131072)               = 5
write(4, "test\n", 5)                   = 5
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
…
```

```
$ strace -v cp -a foo bar
…
 -- original metadata is retrieved
lstat("foo", {st_dev=makedev(254, 0), st_ino=60569468, st_mode=S_IFREG|0644,
             st_nlink=1, st_uid=1000, st_gid=1000, st_blksize=4096, st_blocks=8,
             st_size=5, st_atime=2016-12-28T09:16:59+0200.879714332,
             st_mtime=2016-12-28T09:16:55+0200.816363098,
             st_ctime=2016-12-28T09:16:55+0200.816363098}) = 0
 -- data is copied
open("foo", O_RDONLY|O_NOFOLLOW)        = 3
open("bar", O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC)           = 4
read(3, "test\n", 131072)               = 5
write(4, "test\n", 5)                   = 5
read(3, "", 131072)                     = 0
 -- modifiction time is copied
utimensat(4, NULL, [{tv_sec=1482909419, tv_nsec=879714332},
                    {tv_sec=1482909415, tv_nsec=816363098}], 0) = 0
 -- ownership is copied (only with 'sudo [strace] cp')
fchown(4, 1000, 1000)                   = 0
 -- extended attributes are copied (xdg.origin.url is set by browsers, wget)
flistxattr(3, NULL, 0)                  = 0
flistxattr(3, "user.xdg.origin.url\0", 20) = 20
fgetxattr(3, "user.xdg.origin.url", "https://superuser.com/", 22) = 22
fsetxattr(4, "user.xdg.origin.url", "https://superuser.com/", 22, 0) = 0
 -- POSIX ACLs are not present, so a basic ACL is built from st_mode
 -- (in this case, a simple fchmod() would work as well)
fgetxattr(3, "system.posix_acl_access", 0x7ffc87a50be0, 132) = -1 ENODATA (No data available)
fsetxattr(4, "system.posix_acl_access", "\2\0\0\0\1\0\6\0\377\377\377\377\4\0\4\0\377\377\377\377 \0\4\0\377\377\377\377", 28, 0) = 0
close(4)                                = 0
close(3)                                = 0
…
```

Comment: to complement this answer you should mention : - when copying to another drive: the metadata is read from the source, and reproduced on the target if the appropritate settings (or options) (for ex: keep date, keep rights, or even keep "everything") were used (as you mentionned).  2) An alternative is to first do an archive (.zip, .tar, etc) of the files, and extract from this archive on the target, once again giving the program some place (in the archive format) to find the metadata, and specific options/settings allow one to keep (or not) those metadatas.

Comment: To the second paragraph: What about stat(2)?

Comment: Thanks for giving me a detailed answer to this one question I've pondered about.

Answer (score 11):

It generally differs from filesystem to filesystem where the metadata is stored. On the ext2-family of filesystems, the metadata you mentioned (owner, group, permissions, time) are stored in the [inode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode). The inode also stores (pointers to) the blocks the file occupies on disk. The inode does *not* store the filename.

You can access this data with the `stat` system call (`man 2 stat`), and use the `stat` tool to print it (`man stat`). A detailed description of the inode fields can be found in `linux/include/linux/fs.h` in the kernel source.

There are other kinds of metadata (e.g. [ACL permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Access_control_list)) that are stored in different places.

Metadata is not copied by default when you copy the file. Instead, a new file with default metadata values is created. There are various options to `cp` (`-p`, `--preserve`) which instruct `cp` to also copy metadata, by reading the old metadata with `stat` and modifying the new metadata accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on the file system, areas are reserved either (semi-)statically or dynamically to hold metadata such as permissions, size, and others (sometimes the file name too).

In Unix, metadata is stored in the *inode* controlling the data area where the file resides ([while file names and related inode numbers are stored in a directory entry](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/117334/41216)).

In some filesystems directory entries are files like any other, but hidden from view. FAT and FAT32 are such filesystems (FAT's root directory is "special" though). When you create a file, you add/edit an entry in the file that describes the folder where the file resides. Each entry is large enough to store file size, name and date, and nothing else (long names occupying multiple entries; the default entry size of 32 bytes can hold a single name in the old 8+3 character format. All this, of course, assuming my memory is working). Ext system is similar, but the directory entry is dynamically sized and holds only the name and the inode pointer; all other information is in the inode. This way, two entries may point to the same file, which is useful to manage duplicate files.

In some filesystems, inodes can be large enough to hold a small amount of data in addition to the metadata, so that if the file can fit there, it does not occupy extra disk space. You create a 45-byte file and the free disk space does not change at all; those bytes are stored *inside* the inode. I think that the ext* family supports this (and NTFS too). This helps to manage large number of very small files.

In yet other file systems, there's what amounts to a "phantom" file system along the main one, that stores these extra attributes. Not only [file information but possibly file icons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_fork) as well.

Some systems have both: NTFS has the full directory metadata working in inode-like fashion, and the possibility to create [*alternate data streams*](https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/windows-alternate-data-streams/) holding further information that does not (apparently) change anything in the "main" file.

Comment: File names aren't stored with the file, they're part of the directory inode. That's why hard links work

Comment: this answer conflicts with dirkt's about where filenames are stored, i wonder which is correct

Comment: Sorry, I mixed up things, and **@dirkt has the right of it**. Fixing answer.

Comment: They're part of the _directory_, but usually _not_ part of the directory's inode. It's FS-specific, but if you think of a directory as a special file, then its _contents_ would be the list of files (names and their inodes).